# Is there an explicit construction of a universal graph on countable vertices?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I just learned that almost every random graph whose vertices are $\mathbb{N}$ is universal.  However, this says nothing about coming up with a single explicit universal graph.  Is this an easy task?

Comment: It’s the *Rado graph*; there’ a very simple explicit construction in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rado_graph#Construction_via_binary_numbers), and the proof of universality given there is also pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is called the **Rado graph**.